# Gmail Hides common text

Tags: html, html-email, php

In my website I am sending my clients, email using php mail function. The mail usually contains an html tag as message(hope you understand what i am saying). There are three divs inside the html tag. First div contains my company's header, second one contains dynamic message and the third one is for the footer message. Except for the second header, the other two headers doesn't change and here comes the problem. Gmail detects the first and last divs as signature and hide it as a quoted text. How can I stop that?

Comment: for emails it's recommended to use `tables` instead of `divs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had that problem in testing, gmail will quote duplicate content.

Just don't send with a subject line.

And although unrelated: definitely don't use divs or floats (use tables), and inline everything for gmail.